# Navigating to the base url in bamboo's build but working fine on Local

Tags: java, selenium, maven, testng, bamboo

**Scenario:**

My `baseUrl/Login` is something like this https://example.com/#/ and its opening in the `1st tab`. After entering the credentials, it is https://example.com/#/verification. I am navigating from here to another url which is opened in `2nd tab`. But when it backs to `1st tab`, It's changing to the `baseUrl` again.

**Code:**

```java
public void visitMailinator() throws InterruptedException {
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open()");
    ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
    driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    driver.get(url);
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    first_mail.click();
    Reporter.log("First mail is clicked ", true);
    driver.switchTo().frame("html_msg_body");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    String verificationToken = token.getText();
    Reporter.log("The Verification Token is: " + verificationToken, true);
    Reporter.log("Browser is Navigating back", true);
    Thread.sleep(6000);

    driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(0));
    Reporter.log("Browser is Navigated back", true);
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    String link = driver.getCurrentUrl();

    Reporter.log("current Link is: " + link, true);
    
    driver.navigate().to("https://example/#/verification"); // Its not working
    
    code_field.isDisplayed();
    code_field.sendKeys(verificationToken);
    Reporter.log("Verification Key is Entered", true);

}
```

Comment: You can't rely on the index-order of the window handles.  Use getWindowHandle() to get the current handle.  Then open the new tab... find the handle in getWindowHandles() that is not the current handle to switch to the new tab.  (This may not be the problem here, but worth noting...)

Comment: @pcalkins I am already using it